# Appcelerator: The best way to create a Cart

Tags: shopping-cart, appcelerator-alloy

I wanna do an app store, and I need program a CART. This cart need to be a global var. Then, I think that i have two options:

1- Create a Global object  with Alloy.Globals.

2- Create a new Modal and work with Collection.

Are there any other options? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

If the cart is an object or you must save data in database, colletion is better option, because you can list data saved more easily.